# Postman: Can i save JSON objects to environment variable so as to chain it for another request?

Tags: json, postman

I tried using the `postman.setEnvironmentVariable()` method in which I can set simple numbers and string values. My question is when I tried saving an object, it saves as `[object Object]`. I want to know if it is possible to save a JSON object so I can use it in another Request.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use **JSON.stringify()** before setting it to environment variable.

Then after you call it in next request, use **JSON.parse()** to recreate the object.

Hope it helps.