# Can't access a javascript Object via Postman's environment variables

Tags: javascript, object, automated-tests, postman

I am new to postman API testing.
Recently I am using it's collection runner to test request iteration with data file(json).
The weird thing is if I try to access the environment variable that I set before, the console log always shows `[object Object]` instead of `Object {}`.

Here's my pre-request code on postman:

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("username", data.username);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("password", data.password);
```

and the Tests code on postman:

```
var userData = {
    username: environment.username,
    password: environment.password
};

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("user", userData);

console.log(environment.user);

for(var key in environment.user){
    console.log(key + ": "+ environment.user[key]);
}
```

Request URL: [https://echo.getpostman.com/get?username={{username}}&password={{password}}](https://echo.getpostman.com/get?username=%7B%7Busername%7D%7D&password=%7B%7Bpassword%7D%7D)

data.json:

```
[{
    "username" : "Jon Snow",
    "password" : "iloveGot123"
},{
    "username" : "Akali",
    "password" : "iWillKickyalla55"
},{
    "username" : "Ricky Grimmes",
    "password" : "rg0123455"
}]
```

Please help thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postman: Can i save JSON objects to environment variable so as to chain it for another request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479494/postman-can-i-save-json-objects-to-environment-variable-so-as-to-chain-it-for-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> postman.setEnvironmentVariable(variableName, variableValue): Sets an environment variable “variableName”, and assigns the string “variableValue” to it. You must have an environment selected for this method to work. **Note: Only strings can be stored. Storing other types of data will result in unexpected behavior.**

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/sandbox

So basically it's showing that because it wants a string only.

You can wrap the object with `JSON.stringify()` to convert it to a string and then use `JSON.parse()` when you want to turn it back into an object.