# reuse json body value in another request as input?

Tags: json, variables, console, postman

Have dynamic generated post request for student pass every time send post method and want to use this dynamic_value in another request as an input. How to use this ?

{ "study pass":"dynamic_value"}

Used below but not storing that dynamic value in variable.

var Json=JSON.parse(responsebody);
postman.setEnviormentVariable("study pass",jsonData.study_pass);

output (dynamic_value) from Request 1 > need to be used as input for Request 2

Comment: study pass is temporary pass for student which needs to be updated by another request

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking here, what you're asking you seem to have already answered. Can you clarify some more?

Comment: i want to use output value i.e. "dynamic_value" from Request 1 and input to Request 2. and with above by parsing json, but i am not getting that dynamic value in variable, so thats the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postman: Can i save JSON objects to environment variable so as to chain it for another request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479494/postman-can-i-save-json-objects-to-environment-variable-so-as-to-chain-it-for-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on where you want to use the environment variable `study pass`, you can use:

- `{{study pass}}` in the URL, request body, request headers. form data
- `pm.environment.get('study pass')` in the pre-request script or test

But you're setting a variable `Json`, but when calling `setEnvironmentVariable`, your using `jsonData`.
With consistent naming, your problem should be fixed.

Comment: Variable showing null when used {{temp_token}}
```var tempvar = console.log(pm.response.json()["temp token"]);
showing 
temp_token = JSON.stringify(tempvar);
pm.environment.set("temp_token", temp_token); ```