# saving arrays in one call and use it in another call in postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

I am trying to use chain request feature in postman.
Here is my first request:
[image]

As you see I am trying to save configs as an array to use it in another request. Apparently post man save the array in env vars as an strings.
So here I need to use the above array:

[image]

but not sure how as when I debug the configs sent I do not see array and instead I see:

```
"configuration_ids":"b21aecaa-ff79-422a-b8b3-430a32d10242,e081163f-bfeb-4462-a753-b6e0bc5b00f5,c7c0fe31-62dd-4d5d-8d57-4122cdd5394f,64896a72-40c2-4271-ab03-12b73a2e55d8,55abc706-9ed6-4f04-90dd-22c668310584"
```

Any help on how to achieve this is appreciated

Comment: What does the response from `/configurations` endpoint look like?

Comment: @Z.Kosanovic similar to this:  {
    "b21aecaa-ff79-422a-b8b3-430a32d10242": {
      .....
    },
    "e081163f-bfeb-4462-a753-b6e0bc5b00f5": {
        "acl": {
        ........

Comment: Okay, so the second line gets the keys and then joins them to string. Not sure if this would work, but try to delete the join part. So, it's just `... = Object.keys(response);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postman: Can i save JSON objects to environment variable so as to chain it for another request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479494/postman-can-i-save-json-objects-to-environment-variable-so-as-to-chain-it-for-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `join`, as already pointed out in the comments.

Still, setting an environment variable calls `toString()`, thus you need to stringify `configurationIds`:

```
const configurationIds = Object.keys(response)

pm.environment.set("configurationIds", JSON.stringify(configurationIds));
```

When I set this body in the next request

```
{"configuration_ids":{{configurationIds}}}
```

it results in:

```
{
   "configuration_ids":[
      "b21aecaa-ff79-422a-b8b3-430a32d10242",
      "e081163f-bfeb-4462-a753-b6e0bc5b00f5"
   ]
}
```